# Problem with setting a value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, return-value

Here is my code snippit:

```
- (void) getData: (NSNotification *)aNotification{
NSData *data = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];

if ([data length])
{
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
} else {
    [self stopProcess];
}

[[aNotification object] readInBackgroundAndNotify];  
}
```

Ok, so how do I set an NSString to the value of getData anywhere else in my application?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you can't return an `NSString` object from a `void` function.

Secondly, it looks like this method is triggered via the notification system. Setting an `NSString` to a value of `getData` *anywhere* in your application would require having (a) an object, and (b) a way to set an `NSString` on that object.

Basically, notifications happen asynchronously. Your `getData` method can only extract the string value and pass it via a message to other objects it knows about.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this notification message is a member of a class, I would use an instance variable to store the latest value of the string so that other clients that need it could read the last known value.

Comment: Ok....I don't want to use NSNotification. I just want to get the data. How do I do that? BTW...this is from the moriarity app

Comment: The code you posted USES a notification and it looks like a notification handler. If you are listening to notifications, you will have to do it somewhat similarly as your code, capturing the value of the notification somewhere.